# Different "jpeg" extensions and php's getimagesize()

Tags: php, image, jpeg, mime-types, getimagesize

So, some img has `.jpg` extension, some `.jpeg`, some `.JPG` and also some `.JPEG`.

Question: for php function `getimagesize()`, these 4 extensions is same and  will always return `image/jpeg` as mime type ?

Comment: Yes they will, the extension doesn't really matter to be honest. You could pass a jpg with the extension .poop and it'd still have the mimetype of image/jpeg. You could very easily test this question yourself in the time it took to write this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mimetype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) of a file is something different then the [extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension) of the file. The mimetype is usually determined by [reading the (partial) contents of a file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_sniffing).

Comment: Thank you Wesley, after 3 minute You have one more accepted answer